# Linker error when trying to call C++ code from Swift

Tags: c++, xcode, swift, linker-errors

I am trying to call a simple C++ function from Swift, but I am getting the **Apple Mach-O Linker Error**:

[image: Error]

[image: Error 2]

My Sample.h file (C++):

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    int getOne();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

My Sample.cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getOne()
{
    return 1;
}
```

My bridging header:

```
#include "Sample.h"
```

---

I am trying to call the function as simple as:

```
println(getOne())
```

**Notes:**

I did add the C++ library to the Project and to the build Libraries (Build phases), I tried this code with Xcode 6.2 (Swift 1.1) and with Xcode 6.3 (beta Swift 1.2), and same error occours.

I did add the bridging header to the Build settings.

I've read something about wrapping my C++ code in Obj-c, but I haven't quite been able to manage that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The *declaration* is marked `extern "C"`, but not the *definition*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already stated in a comment, the error is that only the function 
declaration is marked extern "C", but not the definition.

So when compiling the Swift source file, the compiler creates
a reference to the symbol "_getOne", but when compiling "Sample.cpp",
the C++ mangled symbol " __Z6getOnev" is defined. Therefore linking
the program fails.

A solution is to include "Sample.h" from "Sample.cpp":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Sample.h"

int getOne()
{
    return 1;
}
```

so that the `extern "C"` linkage-specification is applied to the function definition as well.

It is generally good practice to include the .h file from the corresponding .c/.cpp/.m file to ensure that the implementation 
matches the public interface.